# Receiving Null When Passing from Front end to back end pdf file for uploading

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to upload pdf file from client side to the backend and keep path for storing in database. .

**Div within a section in the HTML file **

```
 <div class="row mb-3">
     <label @* for="upload_file" *@ class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Upload</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
         **<input class="form-control" type="file" id="upload_file" accept="application/pdf" >**
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn btn-outline-info" value="Upload" id="btn_upload" /> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

But receiving the 'null' values always in 'cfile' parameter in Controller method

**Controller Method**

```
public async Task<bool>  Upload_pdf([FromForm] IFormFile cfile)
 {
     string path = "";
     bool iscopied = false;

     try
     {
         if (cfile.Length > 0)
         {
             string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(cfile.FileName);
             path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload"));

             using (var filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, filename), FileMode.Create))
             {
                 await cfile.CopyToAsync(filestream);
             }
             iscopied = true;
         }
     }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }

     return iscopied;
 }



$('#upload_file').change(function (e) {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myFile = $('#upload_file').val();
        var file_type = myFile.split('.').pop();
        /* var file_size = myFile.files[0].size;*/
        var file_length = myFile.length;
        var file_size = e.target.files[0].size;

        if (file_type === 'pdf' || file_type === 'pdf')
        {
            if (file_size > 524288) {
                alert('Please select the file less than 512KB !!!');
                $('#upload_file').val('');
            }
            else {
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append('cfile', myFile);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Form/Upload_pdf',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: form,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('visited')
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, type, exception) {
                        alert("Error - " + exception);
                    }


                })
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#upload_file').val('');
            alert('Please select only pdf file');
        }
    }
    catch (e) { alert('Error while uploading -' + e); }
})
```

please suggest to solve the same as why the control argument is not receiving the proper file which is being supplied by the jquery ajax call.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?  Why haven't you tagged the language you're actually using?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your codes ,`var myFile = $('#upload_file').val();` doesn't really get the file.
You could use

```
var myFile = document.getElementById("upload_file").files[0];
```

or

```
var myFile= $('#upload_file').prop('files')[0];
```

The ajax call has no problem.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I have modified it little bit and make all code available on button click and use  var myFile = document.getElementById("upload_file").files[0]; for accessing file on uploader input type.

Comment: @DevenderSingh Please help to accept this answer if it works for you:)

Comment: I have already put one vote, but it is asking saying "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @DevenderSingh Thanks all the same. You could reference this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers about asker actions.